# Delphi Write Multi parameters in Named Pipes

Tags: delphi, parameters, pipe, named-pipes

In Delphi i'm using "Libby's pipes.pas" this Unit https://micksmix.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/named-pipes-unit-for-delphi/

I'm able to communicate with another process, my problem comes when i want to pass more than one parameter, and the size is not fixed.
Like wanting to write 1 array of bytes plus 2 dwords.
And in the server shall i guess the length of the 1st parameter? I don't think so. Hope somebody that had been messing with this unit would know how to point me in the right way.

Thanks in advance.

```
    procedure SendDatapipe(buf:TArray<Byte>;tipe,siz:dword);
    begin
    if FClient1=nil then begin
    FClient1 := TPipeClient.CreateUnowned;
    FClient1.PipeName := 'PipeServer';
    if FClient1.Connect=False then
    FClient1:=nil;
    end;
    if (FClient1<>nil) and (FClient1.connected=FALSE) then
    FClient1.Connect;
    if (FClient1<>nil) and (FClient1.connected) then

    FClient1.Write(buf[0], Length(buf));
//WHAT ELSE?
    FClient1.FlushPipeBuffers;
    FClient1.Free;
    end;
```

I noticed that FClient1.Write can also use a "PRefix", i'm not sure whether this is what i'm looking for.

Comment: Write the length of the array first, then the array. Then the reader can read the length, and know how much to expect. Pass dyn arrays as `const` params to avoid needless expensive copies.

Comment: I got you, so making kindof a header for every parameter i pass.
And in the server reading always the first 4 bytes to know the length of each parameter.

Comment: That's right. You might prefer to use something like JSON if the structure becomes more complex.

Comment: There are a number of methods and libraries to "Serialize objects" - or records. Like in Synopse mORMot (there is explicit support for records with published RTTI, not only for objects), or life in VCL itself, streaming components to/from VCL. Maybe that is the way to go for you - to send object/records serialized

Comment: check this also: libs and tools mentioned in comments there might give you insights to take another approach to your app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740771

Comment: if you would still choose to hard-code this all from scratch without using ready-made tools, learn the concept https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value - you would make different versions of both server and client, and would you hardcode format into programs, - one day someone would run different versions of client and server at it would crash. The format of data should be described and decided out of the programs implementing it. Then you would be able to make ur programs to adapt to the data they get

Comment: some ready standards: Delphi DFM, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Binary_Meta_Language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML